# TIFF Convertion issue for Rich TIFF format

Tags: silverlight, tiff, libtiff.net

I am using [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) to convert the TIFF images to writable bitmaps to display in my siverlight application.

For the below header formats I am able to convert successfully:

```
static byte[] tiff = new byte[] { 73, 73, 42 };         // TIFF     
static byte[] tiff2 = new byte[] { 77, 77, 42 };         // TIFF
```

If the TIFF header is something like { 60, 63, 120 } the library is failing to read the image.

Answer (score 0):

`{ 60, 63, 120 }` is `{ 0x3C, 0x3F, 0x78 }` which is `<?x` in ASCII

It looks like you are trying to open an XML file (which starts from `<?xml`). Or you are trying to open broken TIFF without required header.